# Do I have to write the "GO" word in order to execute an SQL server statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have little to no experience with TSQL and SQL Server - so in MySQL when I want to execute a statement I simply write:

```
Select * from users
```

...and then hit ENTER.

However now I see many SQL Server tutorials that you have the `GO` word immediately after each statement. Do I have to write this? For example:

```
Select * from users; GO
```

Or I can simply write:

```
Select * from users; <enter key pressed...>
```

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server, `go` separates query batches.  It's optional in most situations.

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you had to do a `go` after altering a table, like:

```
alter table MyTable add MyColumn int
go
select MyColumn from MyTable
```

If you didn't, SQL Server would parse the query batch, and complain that MyColumn didn't exist.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a
>   signal that they should send the
>   current batch of Transact-SQL
>   statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of
>   statements is composed of all
>   statements entered since the last GO,
>   or since the start of the ad hoc
>   session or script if this is the first
>   GO.

Comment: Instead of enter you can just hit F5 to execute the query

Comment: @leo: One more thing, though you will find it on the page linked by Andomar, should be stated clearly: `GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.` That is, remember not to use it in your client's queries, because the engine will not recognise it but will raise a syntax error instead.

Answer (score 2):

[GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) separates batches, as Andomar wrote.

Some SQL statements (e.g. [CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)) need to be the first or only statements within a batch. For example, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) states

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot
>   be combined with other Transact-SQL
>   statements in a single batch.

Local variables are also limited to a batch, and therefore are not accessible after a GO.

Answer (score 1):

Go is optional, no need  to write that in your sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to.  What the GO will do is execute each statement (at least in Sql Server)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerers said before me, you don't really NEED `Go`.

There is only one case when you have to use it, and that's when you want to create a table or view and then select from it.

For example:

```
create view MyView as select * from MyTable   
go   
select * from MyView
```

Without `Go`, Sql Server won't execute this because the select statement is not valid, because the view doesn't exist at that moment.

Comment: Not true. The reason `GO` is needed there is because it denotes the end of the `CREATE` statement. Since SQL Server 2005 there is statement level compilation and compilation is deferred if the object does not currently exist.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I just tried it on SQL Server 2008 R2 - without Go, the query doesn't run.

Comment: I know it doesn't run. But not for the reason you suggest. `exec ('create view MyView as select * from MyTable'); select * from MyView` works fine. If you mouse over the red wavy line in SSMS you will see the actual complaint is that `CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in a batch`. Also try `create table mytable(c int); select * from mytable`

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work either. Using GO is the only way that I know of how to do this with one query instead of two.

Comment: It works fine. I forgot the brackets in my first version though.